# Inno Setup check if WAMP is installed before proceeding

Tags: registry, installation, wamp, inno-setup, wampserver

I'm using Inno Setup to create our installation wizard and it contains a WAMP installation in it. But according to others, double WAMP installation would harm WAMP itself. So I need to check if WAMP is installed before proceeding. Any ways on how to do this?

Comment: *"WAMP or any other related program"* is pretty broad. There's no generic way to check for an "application", let only for *"any other related program"*. You have to implement a specific check for each specific application. So name specific applications you want to check for. And you should probably ask a separate question for each application.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I edited the question. I only now need to check if WAMP is installed. I apologize about that.

Comment: Could you please share some more info about WAMP? E.g. what registry entries it creates, what executables it contains? Or where to download it (if this is free or OpenSource app? I am pretty sure that noone will be able to give you proper answer without specific information about the WAMP app. 
What I would do would be: 1. Check for registry entry with path, 2. Take path and check if it exists, 3. Check if executable of app exists in app path, and maybe 4. Check if this is known version of app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAMP creates registry entries during the installation process. The installer is based on Inno Setup.

There are 2 classes of registry entries:

1 Individual:

```
[Registry]

Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\"; 
ValueName: "{app}\wampmanager.exe"; ValueType: String; ValueData: "RUNASADMIN"; 
Check: "IsWin64"; MinVersion: 0.0,6.0; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty 
Root: HKLM32; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\"; 
ValueName: "{app}\wampmanager.exe"; ValueType: String; ValueData: "RUNASADMIN"; 
Check: "Not IsWin64"; MinVersion: 0.0,6.0; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
```

2 Default Uninstallation information:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{wampserver64}_is1` with path in `InstallLocation`

That allows us to check if WAMP is installed and if Executable is present in installation folder (as an additional check).

Example is based on `64-bit` version of WAMP 3.0.6.

It needs to be adjusted if support for both `32- and 64-bit` versions is required.

```pascal
[Setup]
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64[

[Code]
function CheckWAMPExists(): Boolean;
var
  sInstPath: String;
  sInstallString: String;
begin
  Result := False;
  sInstPath := 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{wampserver64}_is1';
  sInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sInstPath, 'InstallLocation', sInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sInstPath, 'InstallLocation', sInstallString);
  if sInstallString <> '' then begin
    if FileExists(ExpandConstant(sInstallString) + 'wampmanager.exe') then
    MsgBox('WAMP found!' + #13#10 + 'Install location:' + #13#10 + sInstallString 
    + #13#10#13#10 + 'Installation will proceed!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := True;
  end
  else begin
    MsgBox('WAMP not found! Installation terminated.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
    Result := CheckWAMPExists;
end;
```

Comment: If the answer above solves your problem, please accept it as a solution.

Comment: Sorry, haven't checked in for a while. I think this solves it. Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can come up of checking if a program is installed is by checking if their default and other possible paths have their folder.

```
if DirExists('C:\wamp')
or DirExists('C:\wamp64')
or DirExists('C:\Program Files\wamp') 
or DirExists('C:\Program Files\wamp64') 
or DirExists('C:\Program Files(x86)\wamp')
or DirExists('C:\Program Files(x86)\wamp64')
or DirExists('{userdocs}\wamp')
or DirExists('{userdocs}\wamp64')
or DirExists('{userdocs}\Desktop\wamp')
or DirExists('{userdocs}\Desktop\wamp64')
    then begin
        MsgBox('An installation of WAMP was found.' + #13#10#13#10 + 'Please uninstall any WAMP/XAMPP programs first' + #13#10 + 'or install SpinShot in a different PC.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I believe that this is not the best solution. That would require to scan all disc and all directories, as (probably) user can install WAMP anywhere. Can you share some details about this WAMP? E.g. where to download installer from - if this is Open Source or Freeware? It's possible that WAMP creates registry entries that would make it easier to look for it and confirm its existence.

Comment: @RobeN here it is: http://www.wampserver.com/en/ and as far as I know, it doesn't edit any registry upon its installation.